# Can't delete corrupted .png.icloud in MacBook Pro M1

Tags: finder, storage, macos, trash

Recently one of my friends sent me some screenshot files from WhatsApp and I downloaded it to my MacBook, those files were screenshot.png.icloud files. Once they are on my downloads folder, I can't open, copy, move or delete those files. When I try to delete these files, I get this error message "The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -50).". I can open, copy, move, delete every other files, but not .png.icloud files. Since those images can't be opened, I think they are corrupted. But those files can't be even deleted.

**Solutions I tried which non of them worked,**

- Restarted the MacBook and tried deleting the files and didn't work.
- Restarted MacBook in Safe Boot and tried but didn't work.
- Created, a different administrator account and tried to access the my account's download folder but I couldn't get access to the download folder from that account.
- Did a first aid check on Macintosh HD from Disk Utility and no error's identified.

This should be a bug in macOS 11.6 as I think. Does any one know a work around for this issue. Or maybe how to force delete it or something similar ?

Hardware - MacBook Pro M1, 1TB, 16GB
Software - macOS Big Sur Version 11.6

Comment: Did you try to open a terminal window and delete the files with unix rm command ?